# Automate screenshots of Cordova app (casperJS?)

Tags: cordova, automation, webkit, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm attempting to automate screenshot generation of a Cordova app on a server. My thought was that I could screenshot the HTML source using WebKit and overlay a status bar to product a reasonably accurate screenshot automatically.

I've been using casperJS to do so and it *almost* works. Here is my (trimmed down) code:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 480, height: 640 };
page.clipRect = { width: 480, height: 640 };
page.open(siteURL, function (status) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('phone.png');
        page.close();
        callback.apply();
    }, 4000);
});
```

This produces the screenshot as intended *but* the main screen of the app uses flex box to expand a set of buttons to take up the full height. These buttons are rendered at the smallest size and not "flexed" as they should be.

I believe casperJS is equivalent to an old version of WebKit so perhaps flexbox is not implemented or perhaps casperJS does not set the browser height correctly, either way it's not quite right.

Can anyone suggest a way this could be achieved? Preferably locally but a service would also suffice if necessary.

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have and have you tried upgrading to version 2?

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into problems using PhantomJS to produce screenshots. Things mostly look OK but there are weird rendering issues here and there.

If you need more accuracy, I'd suggest using Selenium WebDriver's built-in screenshot feature to capture images using Chrome (or some other non-PhantomJS browser). For example, using the WebDriver Python bindings, you can use this function:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_screenshot_as_file

You might also look into the bok-choy framework - it's a Selenium wrapper that comes with support for capturing baseline screenshots (for use in visual diff testing), which sounds interesting. As a side effect it seems you might get a bundle of screenshots to use for other purposes.

The bok-choy documentation is found at: http://bok-choy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

And docs for its screenshot features are found at: http://bok-choy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/visual_diff.html